# hup to hung the processes

Tags: bash

I check the current process

```
$ ps
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
  362 ttys000    0:01.67 -bash
  412 ttys001    0:00.52 -bash
 2247 ttys002    0:00.16 -bash
```

with three bashes opened, the current bash is

```
$ echo $$
362
```

I intend to `hup` the other two

```
$ for pid in 412 2247; do hup $pid; done
-bash: hup: command not found
-bash: hup: command not found
```

Nonetheless, I do have a builtin hup

What's wrong with the usage of hup?

Comment: What does 'type hup' output?

Comment: `$ type hup
-bash: type: hup: not found` @Panki

Answer (score 2):

To "hup" a process, send the `HUP` signal to it:

```
kill -s HUP 412 2247
```

"HUP" is short for "hang up" and the `HUP` signal is used to tell a process that the user has "hung up" on it, i.e. logged out or terminated the shell session that the process was started from.  The signal is, for example, automatically sent to all processes started from a shell that runs in a terminal, when that terminal is closed.